# Node.JS Insert data to mongodb Web API , bodyParser issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need an API to android to insert data to mongodb , I'm following [this](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/) , but

```
 var song = req.body;  TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
```

I google few answer , which was need to install bodyParser , so I follow [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to install bodyParser , but still get

```
 var song = req.body;  TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
```

I'm not sure where I do wrong , please help

app code

```
var express = require('express'),
songs = require('./routes/route');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();


app.post('/songs', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
// create user in req.body
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

    app.get('/songs',songs.addSong);
```

route cote

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var uri = "mongodb://XXXXXX:XXXXXXXX@ds061365.mongolab.com:61365/aweitest";
mongoose.connect(uri);
// we're connected!
var db = mongoose.connection.db;
var BSON = require('bson').BSONPure;
var body = require('body-parser');


db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection errrrrrrrror:'));
//db = mongoose.connection.db;
db.once('open', function() {
console.log("mongodb is connected!!");
});



exports.addSong = function(req, res) {
 var song = req.body;
 console.log('Adding song: ' + JSON.stringify(song));
 db.collection('songs', function(err, collection) {
 collection.insert(song, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
  } else {
    console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
    res.send(result[0]);
  }
});
});
}
```

Comment: In your App Code : 
`var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());`

Specify the modules **In this specific order**. And then see if it runs. You didn't actually used bodyParser in your app. To use it, you must specify `app.use(bodyParser());`

See if this helps and let me know

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera Thank you ! I do what you say , it has no error only this `Fri, 19 Feb 2016 16:09:19 GMT body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares at app.js:5:9
Fri, 19 Feb 2016 16:09:19 GMT body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option at ..\..\node_modules\body-parser\index.js:105:29` Im using Curl to test this api , curl give me some can't resolve problem , trying to figure it out

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera is that possible help me use you curl to test my api is working now or now?

Comment: Let me understand what you're trying to do in your code.

Comment: I'm just want to add a data into data base from android , so I need an api to do it , I can find all , find by id now

Comment: Need the credentials to test the api.

Comment: Please have a look at this blog post : 

https://codeforgeek.com/2015/08/restful-api-node-mongodb/

And use **postman** to test your post api.

Comment: oh! thank you !!! it really help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `jsonParser` in your `GET /songs` route, only your `POST /songs` route. However, `GET` requests typically do not have request bodies. Values are typically passed in the url as query parameters in those cases, so you will probably want to instead look in `req.query`.